# Passing a variable as an argument to a UNIX function

Tags: shell, unix

I intent to pass variable as a parameter to my function .(The purpose of this function is to connect to Terdata,fetch top 10 records from a table and write it to a file).But my function is not called instead the names of the files in the home path are being displayed.

Is there any way to pass argument value as a variable.

Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x
my_first_fn()
{
query="SEL TOP 10 * FROM XYZ.TABLENAME"
${BTEQ} << EOF
.logon ${pSERVER}/${pUSERNAME},${pPWD};
.set width 6000;
.set separator ',';
.set titledashes off;
.EXPORT FILE = '${home}/BTEQ.txt';
${stmt};
.EXPORT RESET

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 
THEN .GOTO EXITERR
.QUIT 0;
.LOGOFF;

.LABEL EXITERR
.QUIT 1;
.LOGOFF;
EOF
}


LOG_FILE=${home}/myscript.log

my_first_fn $query | tee ${LOG_FILE}
```

Thanks in advance...:-)

Comment: Have you tried reducing the scope of your program? I don't think you need to have that SQL stuff in `my_first_fn()` to figure out how to pass arguments to a function. I certainly don't want to bother with it. But looking at your call... why are you *calling* `my_first_fn()` with `$query` as parameter -- `query` being a variable only *defined* within `my_first_fn()`?

Comment: Also, use `set -vx` to see code a. ) before it is executed, b. ) with variables expanded to their values. You should see where "the names of the files in the home path" are sneaking in. Good luck.

Comment: You don't define `BTEQ` in this code, I assume it's in the environment. You define `query` *in the function*, so you're actually passing no arguments when you `my_first_fn $query`. You don't use `query`, and the `stmt` variable is undefined. So the code you're running and the code you show are probably different. The solution to your problem is most likely to **quote your variables**:  `my_first_fn "$query"`

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.As pointed out by @DevSolar I will use simple code for understanding purpose rather than mixing evrything up.Thanks for your advice :-)

Comment: Thanks @shellter, set -vx is very helpful indeed.:-)

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman for your reply,yes you are correct, I didn't define `stmt` variable and expected the script to execute.This is the  part which caused the issue.Rather than this I can directly call the function and mention `SEL TOP 10 * FROM XYZ.TABLENAME` in the function's body.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't define `stmt` variable and expected the script to execute.This is the part which caused the issue.Rather than this I can directly call the function and mention `SEL TOP 10 * FROM XYZ.TABLENAME` in the function's body. – UnixNewbie